# Is it possible to place some portions of my template in other files?

Tags: node.js, pug

I would like to place the navigation portion of my Jade template in a separate file (`navigation.jade`) - is that do-able?

I have layout.jade, and would like to do something like this:

```
mixin ie(condition, content)
  | <!--[!{condition}]>!{content}<![endif]-->

doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    meta(name="description" content="")
    meta(name="author" content="")
    link(href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet")
    link(href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet")
    link(href="/stylesheets/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet")
    link(href="/stylesheets/layout-semiboxed.css" rel="stylesheet")
    link(href="/stylesheets/skin-red.css" rel="stylesheet")
    link(rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico")
    +ie('if lt IE 9', '<script src="/javascripts/html5shiv.js"></script>')
    +ie('if lt IE 9', '<script src="/javascripts/respond.min.js"></script>')
    +ie('if lte IE 8', '<link href="/stylesheets/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet">')
  body(class="off")
    .wrapbox
        section.toparea
            .container
                .row
                    div(class="col-md-6 top-text pull-left animated fadeInLeft")
                    div(class="col-md-6 text-right animated fadeInRight" style="float: right;")
                        .social-icons
                            a(class="icon icon-facebook" href="#")
                            a(class="icon icon-twitter" href="#")
                            a(class="icon icon-linkedin" href="#")
                            a(class="icon icon-skype" href="#")
                            a(class="icon icon-google-plus" href="#")
        black navigation // <-- this is the part I am trying to add
        block content
```

I have created `navigation.jade`, it looks like this:

```
extends layout

block navigation
    nav(class="navbar navbar-fixed-top wowmenu" role="navigation")
        .container
            .navbar-header
                a(class="navbar-brand logo-nav" href="index.html")
                    img(src="/images/mightywash.png" alt="logo")
                ul(id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right")
                    li(class="active")
                        a(href="/") Home
                    li
                        a(href="/locations") Locations
                    li
                        a(href="/charity") Charity
                    li
                        a(href="/washpackages") Wash Packages
                    li
                        a(href="/lubecenters") Oil Change / Lube Centers
                    li
                        a(href="/contact") Contact
```

How do I put the two together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, jade has an include directive.

If you nav bar is in a lot of pages, put it (or include it) into a layout that you extend.  So everybody gets it.  Else just include in a few pages.

The syntax is (e.g., I put a footer at the bottom of every page

```
include ../public/footer1.html
```

I suspect that an "absolute path", e.g. `/public/foo.html` also works - try it (I'm a newbie too).  You can include .jade instead of .html  more Jade examples here: (http://jade-lang.com/reference/#includes)  Here's my complete template (er, I mean layout) to put a header nav bar and footer on every page.  YMMV:

```
doctype 5
html
   head
      title= title
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/nextq1.css')
      block head

   body
      include ../public/header1.html

      block content

      include ../public/footer1.html
```

Comment: what is the include syntax?

Comment: See edits, but in my case it is  `include ../public/header1.html`

Answer (score 0):

include may sometimes require includes tag also..
eg:

```
include includes/footer.jade
```

where footer.jade is same folder as ur current jade file...
u cannot include "include" in script section

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.. and should work!! except in case if you were using `black navigation` instead of `block navigation`.

In case it doesn't work you can try this way..

The simplest way to do this is to use `include`.

You have the file `navigation.jade`.To include this file as if it was the part of `layout.jade`, just add

```
include ./navigation.jade
```

and remove the `block navigation` line.

If using this method, then remove the `extends layout` line from the top of `navigation.jade` file.